# Sonata Admin slow performance, where do I start?

Tags: performance, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a website made with Symfony 2.8 and Sonata Admin.
In the page where I have a `CollectionType` (`sonata_type_collection`) with **inline edit** when I start adding a lot of rows, about 50-100, the page becomes very slow and it takes about 5-10 seconds for a new row to appear.

I exported the graph from the Symfony toolbar but I can't understand where is the culprit, what does "controller" mean?

[image]

Where can I start looking?